# How to map the same column two times in other entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i'm new using hibernate to map entities, i'm trying to use the same column in two different variables for one of my entities, let me explain it, i have an entity called "Matches", this entity will contain information regarding a match, including the localTeam and the awayTeam.

The other entity is Team, one match has two different Teams and Team can have several matches with other Teams.

When i'm try to retrieving all the matches i'm getting an Exception

I'm using SpringBoot 2.1.7, Java 8 and Hibernate 5

```java
@Entity(name = "matches")
public class Matches {

    //Attributes
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "local_team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Team localTeam;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "away_team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Team awayTeam;


@Entity(name = "teams")
public class Team {

    //Attributes
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "localTeam")
    private Matches localMatches;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "awayTeam")
    private Matches awayMatches;
```

When i try to get all the matches loaded , i got this, i can figure is about how i declared the association between Matches an Team, but i'm still confused about how should i declare it.

```java
2019-08-26 00:20:00.145 ERROR 14452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/quinielamx] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 18, for class: com.test.app.models.Matches; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 18, for class: com.test.app.models.Matches] with root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 18, for class: com.test.app.models.Matches
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1151) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1010) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1151) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1010) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1151) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1010) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1151) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1010) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4273) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:481) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1151) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1010) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:346) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.test.app.services.MatchesService.getAllMatches(MatchesService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.test.app.controllers.TestController.getAllMatches(TestController.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

Comment: Use `private List<Team> awayTeam;` instead of `private Team awayTeam;` in `Matches` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a `@oneToMany` connection in with `local/awayTeam  -> matches` because 
a `team` can also play in serveral `matches`.

> |Team A | matches | team B |
>
> |  1    |   a     |   2    |
>
> |  1    |   b     |   3    |
>
> |  1    |   c     |   4    |
>
> |  1    |   d     |   5    |

and so one

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "localTeam")
private Iterable<Matches> localMatches;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "awayTeam")
private Iterable<Matches> awayMatches;
```

greatings

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
@Entity(name = "matches")
    public class Matches {

        //Attributes
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "local_team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Team localTeam;

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "away_team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Team awayTeam;


    @Entity(name = "teams")
    public class Team {

        //Attributes
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private Long id;


        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "localTeam")
        private Set<Matches> localMatches;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "awayTeam")
        private Set<Matches> awayMatches;
```

Comment: how `@oneToOne` relation applicable for `Set` type. doesn't the relation say for only one result itself ?

Answer (score 0):

For a team there can be many away and local matches. SO you have to keep a List or set there in Team for fetching matches, as shown below:

Matches

```
    @Entity(name = "matches")
        public class Matches {

            //Attributes
            @Id
            @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
            private Long id;

            @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name = "local_team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            private Team localTeam;

            @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name = "away_team_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            private Team awayTeam;
}
```

Team Entity

```
 @Entity(name = "teams")
    public class Team {

        //Attributes
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
        private Long id;


        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "localTeam")
        private Set<Matches> localMatches=new HashSet<Matches>();

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "awayTeam")
        private Set<Matches> awayMatches=new HashSet<Matches>();

}
```